# Basic MDAS Java Swing Calculator

Tags: java, calculator, swing

I have recently started learning Java and decided to make a basic MDAS calculator in Swing. I am not completely new to programming but I may be making some common mistakes, or not writing the most efficient code.

I wanted to make a calculator that can take multiple numbers and operations before finding the answer using MDAS, instead of just returning the answer after every operation and using it for the next.

*e.g.* `2 * 3 + 4 - 5 / 5 =` **9** instead of **1**

My code consists of a single class. There isn't much code so I didn't know if there was a good reason to split it into multiple classes, however I have never written something like this so please feel free to correct me.

[Repo with example gif and runnable jar](https://github.com/RazerMoon/Basic-MDAS-Java-Calculator)

---

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    private String title = "Basic MDAS Calculator";
    private int currentNumber;
    private JLabel displayLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(currentNumber), JLabel.RIGHT);
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    private boolean isClear = true;
    
    final String[] ops = new String[] {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
    
    private ArrayList<Integer> numHistory = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<String> opHistory = new ArrayList<String>();
    

    public GUI() {
        setPanel();
        setFrame();
    }
    
    private void setFrame() {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBounds(10,10,300,700); 
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    
    private void setPanel() {
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        
        displayLabel.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 42));
        panel.add(displayLabel);
        panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 0)));
        
        createButtons();
    }
    
    private void createButtons() {
        
        // 0-9
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final int num = i;
            
            JButton button = new JButton( new AbstractAction(String.valueOf(i)) { 
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    
                    // If somebody presses "=" and then types a number, start a new equation instead
                    // of adding that number to the end like usual
                    if (!isClear) {
                        currentNumber = 0;
                        isClear = true;
                    }
                    
                    if (currentNumber == 0) {
                        currentNumber = num;
                    } else {
                        currentNumber = currentNumber * 10 + num;
                    }
                    
                    displayLabel.setText(String.valueOf(currentNumber));
                }
            });
            
            panel.add(button);
        }
        
        // +, -, x, /
        for (String op : ops) {
            
            JButton button = new JButton( new AbstractAction(op) { 
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    numHistory.add(currentNumber);
                    currentNumber = 0;
                    
                    opHistory.add(op);
                    displayLabel.setText(op);
                }
            });
            
            panel.add(button);
        }
        
        // =
        JButton button = new JButton( new AbstractAction("=") { 
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            private int i;

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
                // Display result
                numHistory.add(currentNumber);
                
                while (opHistory.size() > 0) {
                    
                    if (opHistory.contains("x")) {
                        i = opHistory.indexOf("x");
                        numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) * numHistory.get(i+1));
                    } else if (opHistory.contains("/")) {
                        i = opHistory.indexOf("/");
                        numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) / numHistory.get(i+1));
                    } else if (opHistory.contains("+")) {
                        i = opHistory.indexOf("+");
                        numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) + numHistory.get(i+1));
                    } else if (opHistory.contains("-")) {
                        i = opHistory.indexOf("-");
                        numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) - numHistory.get(i+1));
                    }
                    
                    opHistory.remove(i);
                    numHistory.remove(i+1);
                }
                
                displayLabel.setText(String.valueOf(numHistory.get(0)));
                
                currentNumber = numHistory.get(0);
                numHistory.clear();
                
                if (isClear) {
                    isClear = false;
                }
            }
        });
        
        panel.add(button);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }

}
```

I would appreciate any tips.

[image: Example calculation]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
package calculator;
```

Package names should associate the software with the author, like `com.github.razemoon.basicmdasjavacaluclator`.

---

```java
public class GUI extends JFrame {
```

For Java nming conventions, you'd normally use UpperCamelCase, and use lowercase even for acronyms, like "Gui", "HtmlWidgetToolkit" or "HtmlCssParser".

---

```java
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
```

You only need this field if it is highly likely that the class will be serialized...in this case, most likely not.

---

```java
final String[] ops = new String[] {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
```

Why is this `package-private`?

Also, `final` arrays are not as `final` as you'd think, the individual values can still be changed. You most likely want an Enum....actually, you want an interface, but in this example, an Enum would most likely do fine enough.

---

```java
    private ArrayList<Integer> numHistory = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private ArrayList<String> opHistory = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Always try to use the lowest common interface for declarations, in this case `List`.

---

```java
    private void setFrame() {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBounds(10,10,300,700); 
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Why are you using `this` here but nowhere else?

---

```java
        this.setResizable(false);
```

Why? Your frame is perfectly resizable as far as I can see. By setting it not-resizable you only make sure that your application becomes unusable under different LaFs and font-sizes.

---

```java
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
```

I'm a very persistent advocate for that you're only allowed to use single-letter variable names if your dealing with dimensions.

```java
for (int number = 0; number <= 9; number++) {
// Or
for (int digit = 0; digit <= 9; digit++) {
```

---

```java
final int num = i;
```

Don't shorten variable names just because you can, the decreased amount of typing is not worth the decreased readability.

---

Regarding the creation of buttons, I like to create helper methods and classes which make the code easier to read, in this case I'd go for lambdas, like this:

```java
private JButton createButton(String text, Runnable action) {
    return new JButton(new AbstractButton(text) {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            action.run();
        }
    })
}

// In createButtons:

panel.add(createButton(Integer.toString(number), () -> {
    // Code for the number button goes here.
}));
```

Another alternative would be to create a `private class NumberAction` which accepts a number in its constructor and performs the associated action. That would also allow you to get rid of the final-redeclaration.

---

```java
private int i;
```

That;s a very bad variable name.

---

```java
    public GUI() {
        setPanel();
        setFrame();
    }
    
    private void setFrame() {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBounds(10,10,300,700); 
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

// ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GUI();
    }
```

It would be better to split the responsibilities here. The frame itself is only responsible with getting its own layout going, while the main method should be responsible for getting the frame displayed.

```java
    public GUI() {
        setPanel();
        setFrame();
    }
    
    private void setFrame() {
        this.setTitle(title);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.setBounds(10,10,300,700); 
        this.setResizable(false);
    }

// ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }
```

---

Your logic does not seem to contain any sort of error handling, I believe pressing an operator button twice in succession should yield an error.

---

Maybe a better approach would be to print the whole expression to the screen as entered, and then apply the [Shunting Yard Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to process that expression.

---

Your logic doesn't do decimals, neither does it gracefully handle overflows. By changing your logic yo use `BigDecimal`s you could handle both easily. Note that you must create `BigDecimal`s with an appropriate `MathContext` to have proper accuracy and behavior.

---

If you want read an already existing implementation, I can recommend [exp4j](https://github.com/fasseg/exp4j) for a math-expression library using floats, [EvalEx](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx) for one using `BigDecimal`, and my own project [jMathPaper](https://gitlab.com/RobertZenz/jMathPaper/) for a calculator which sport different GUIs (regarding abstraction).

Comment: Thank you very much for all the feedback! Especially the lambdas approach. I will make sure to check out the implementations you have sent too.

Pressing an operator button twice in succession didn't cause an exception in my simple testing, so I didn't bother to implement an error message (lazy) and thought the user would notice their mistake when they would get a result of 0. However, I did recently notice the fact that dividing twice will return a "/ by zero" exception (oversight) so I should have implemented it anyway. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

### You can use the array declaration.

When you want an array with pre-defined values that can be constant, you can declare the array anonymously.

```java
  final String[] ops = {"+", "-", "x", "/"};
```

### Use Enums for the operations.

Instead of having an array of operation, I suggest that you create an Enum instead.

```java
public enum Operators {
   PLUS("+"), MINUS("-"), MUL("x"), DIV("/");
   private final String operator;
   Operators(String operator) {
      this.operator = operator;
   }
   public String getOperator() {
      return operator;
   }
}
```

This will give you more advantage than the array, since you will be able to remove the duplication.

```java
//[...]
for (Operators op : Operators.values()) {
   JButton button = new JButton( new AbstractAction(op.getOperator()) {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         numHistory.add(currentNumber);
         currentNumber = 0;

         opHistory.add(op);
         displayLabel.setText(String.valueOf(op.getOperator()));
      }
   });
   panel.add(button);
}
//[...]
```

```java
//[...]
if (opHistory.contains(Operators.MUL)) {
   i = opHistory.indexOf(Operators.MUL);
   numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) * numHistory.get(i + 1));
} else if (opHistory.contains(Operators.DIV)) {
   i = opHistory.indexOf(Operators.DIV);
   numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) / numHistory.get(i + 1));
} else if (opHistory.contains(Operators.PLUS)) {
   i = opHistory.indexOf(Operators.PLUS);
   numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) + numHistory.get(i + 1));
} else if (opHistory.contains(Operators.MINUS)) {
   i = opHistory.indexOf(Operators.MINUS);
   numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) - numHistory.get(i + 1));
}
//[...]
```

Also, in my opinion, this will make the code easier to work with and refactor.

### When dividing, always check the `divisor` before doing the division.

When dividing by zero, there an `java.lang.ArithmeticException` throw by java; I suggest that you add a check :)

### Use the `Queue` instead of the `List` to keep the history.

By using the `List` you have to use an index, the `Queue` to remove the first item ([`java.util.Queue#poll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#poll())); the only drawback, you will need to refactor the actual code to remove the `indexOf`.

```java
private Queue<String> opHistory = new ArrayDeque<>();
```

By doing so, you will make the code shorter.

```java
while (opHistory.size() > 0) {
   Operators currentOperator = opHistory.poll();

   switch (currentOperator) { //Java 14+ Switch, you can use if or the older version of the switch.
       case MUL -> numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) * numHistory.get(i+1));
       case DIV -> numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) / numHistory.get(i+1));
       case PLUS -> numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) + numHistory.get(i+1));
       case MINUS -> numHistory.set(i, numHistory.get(i) - numHistory.get(i+1));
   }

   numHistory.remove(i + 1);
}
```

### Extract the expression to variables when used multiple times.

In your code, you can extract the similar expressions into variables; this will make the code shorter and easier to read.

```java
final Integer first = numHistory.get(i);
final Integer second = numHistory.get(i + 1);
switch (currentOperator) {
    case MUL -> numHistory.set(i, first * second);
    case DIV -> numHistory.set(i, first / second);
    case PLUS -> numHistory.set(i, first + second);
    case MINUS -> numHistory.set(i, first - second);
}
```